# sorting out the coordinate and respective solution values for plotting

Tags: plotting, filtering, sorting, discontinuity, datadrop

I want to plot for coordinates and corresponding solution values below.

```
 coor = {0.,6000., 2000., 4000., 8000., 10000., 6000., 12000., 8000., 10000.}
 ϕvalue = {{1.}, {0.178533}, {1.0287}, {0.709987}, {}, {},
    {0.138083}, {0.00703084}, {-0.059974}, {0.01218}}
```

For that I have removed the empty solution ({}) values from the
*ϕvalue* vector by using DeleteCases and Flatten. But unfortunately I could not delete or remove the respective coordinate values. Because of that I am not getting the corresponding *ϕvalue* for the coordinate which are repeating and also solution *ϕvalue* values for repeating coordinates are getting interchanged in between.

See below output which is not in correct pair.

> ```
> {{0.,1.}, {0.,1.}, {2000.,1.0287}, {4000.,0.709987}, {6000.,-0.059974},
>   {6000.,0.178533}, {8000.,0.138083}, {10000.,0.00703084}, {12000.,0.01218}}
> ```

My question is how to skip the every 5th and 6th coordinate value and also the cooresponding empty solution value?

I have already checked the Drop and Exclusion commands, but could not make them work.

> ```
> (Debug) Out[18]= {0., 6000., 2000., 4000., 0., 8000., 10000., 6000., 12000., 8000., 10000.}
> ```

> ```
> (Debug) Out[20]= {{1.}, {0.178533}, {1.0287}, {0.709987}, {1.}, {}, {},{0.138083}, {0.00703084}, {-0.059974}, {0.01218}}
> ```

> ```
> (Debug) Out[22]= {{1.}, {0.178533}, {1.0287}, {0.709987}, {1.}, {}, {},{0.138083}, {0.00703084}, {-0.059974}, {0.01218}}
> ```

```
y = Flatten[p]
```

> ```
> (Debug) Out[23]= {1., 0.178533, 1.0287, 0.709987, 1., 0.138083, 0.00703084, -0.059974, 0.01218}
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cϕ = SortBy[First] @ Select[Length@# == 2 &]@Join[List /@ coor, ϕvalue, 2];


ListLinePlot[cϕ]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
cϕ2 = SortBy[First][Flatten /@ Select[FreeQ[{}]]@Transpose[{coor, ϕvalue}]];

cϕ3 = SortBy[First][Flatten /@ DeleteCases[{_, {}}]@Transpose[{coor, ϕvalue}]];

cϕ == cϕ2 == cϕ3
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: SortBy[First] @ Select[Length@# == 2 &]@Join[List /@ coor, ϕvalue, 2] could you please explain the syntax from Select[]?

Comment: @user75507, `SortBy[First] @ Select[Length@# == 2 &]@Join[List /@ coor, ϕvalue, 2]` is an alternative way to write `SortBy[ Select[Join[List /@ coor, ϕvalue, 2],Length@# == 2 &], First]`.  The part `Join[List /@ coor, ϕvalue, 2]` gives a list of lists; the elements that correspond to `{}` in `ϕvalue` have length 1 and the ones we want  have length 2; hence we use the selector function `Length[#] ==2&`.